# Appcelerator Titanium - Session Management

Tags: javascript, html, session, titanium, hybrid

Is there any predefined method to maintain a session in Appcelerator Titanium studio. Like javascript has support session management as follows

```
// Storage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Retrieval
var field = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Destroy
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');
```

Is there any way to use these functionality  in an Appcelerator Titanium Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are properties in Titanium. Please have a look at it in the Documentation. The docs are pretty well laid out! (So this question shouldn't have to be asked).

That being said, documentation about properties [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties)

```
var foo = Ti.App.Properties.getString('foo');
```

Properties are stored cross session